# Need to take limit of divergence in spherical coordinates on the $\theta=0$ axis

Tags: limits, spherical-coordinates, divergence-operator

The title pretty much says it all.  I need to take the standard expression (one of the standard expressions, I guess) for the divergence of a vector and of a rank-2 tensor in spherical coordinates and find the correct limits at $\theta\rightarrow 0$.  It is clear to me that there are a couple of infinities that exactly cancel at this limit, and there are at least a few places where L'Hopital's rule comes into play, but keeping track of all the $O(\theta)$ terms is making my eyes cross.  Does anyone know of somewhere where this has already been done?

Comment: Hey, I had a similar question about applying limits at $\theta=0$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299244/limit-of-divergence-operator-at-theta-0-in-spherical-coordinates . Were you able to figure it out? I feel like applying L'Hopital's rule here wouldn't necessarily be correct (in my case atleast) since it might not be in 0/0 form.

Comment: @Skawang  Nope, sorry, never got it.  I'm really working this as a numerical problem and I found a grid where I could get a decent (I hope) approximation while avoiding $\theta=0$.